# PostgreSQL - Query to determine the ideal price a product was purchased at vs viewed / added to basket

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently working through some coursework, and I'm having some trouble with one of my queries. Essentially, the idea is to create a dummy data warehouse and create some valuable queries. My first query is to the determine the ideal price a product was purchased at vs whether the user just viewed it or added it to their basket.

Below is an image of the star schema I have for this, although for the query I'm currently writing, only the **Basket** (Fact Table), **Product**, **Product_Interaction**, **Year**, **Month** and **Date** are in use.

[image: tables and their relationships]

This is what I have currently as a query:

```
SELECT p.product_name, 
       p.product_cost, 
       b.product_session_price, 
       pi.interactiontype, 
       y.yearid, 
       m.month_name, 
       m.monthid 
FROM   product p 
       LEFT JOIN basket b 
              ON p.productid = b.productid 
       INNER JOIN product_interaction pi 
               ON b.interactionid = pi.interactionid 
       LEFT JOIN date d 
              ON b.dateid = d.dateid 
       LEFT JOIN year y 
              ON d.year = y.yearid 
       LEFT JOIN month m 
              ON d.month = m.monthid 
WHERE  d.month BETWEEN 1 AND 12 
GROUP  BY pi.interactiontype, 
          p.product_cost, 
          b.product_session_price, 
          p.product_name, 
          y.yearid, 
          m.month_name, 
          m.monthid 
ORDER  BY y.yearid, 
          m.monthid ASC
```

This is currently producing the following:

```
product_name | product_cost | product_session_price | product_interaction | yearid | month_name | monthid

Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $46.00      Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $66.00      Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $70.00      Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $84.00      Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $224.00 Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $304.00 Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $384.00 Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $456.00 Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $671.00 Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $708.00 Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $719.00 Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $745.00 Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $847.00 Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $915.00 Add to Basket   2017    January 1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28   $918.00 Add to Basket   2017    January 1

// ... and thousands more records
```

The **product_interaction** table contains three values:

- View
- Buy
- Added to Basket

The **Year** table contains the following:

- 2017
- 2018
- 2019

The **Month** table contains all the twelve months from *January to December*

The **Day** table just contains integers from *1-31*.

The **Date** table, although not clearly shown in the star schema just contains foreign keys to the *Day*, *Month* and *Year* tables.

The **Product** table just contains random products and prices.

Now, what I'd like to achieve is to have a query that for a given time/date displays the ***ideal*** price in which a given product was purchased, vs viewed/added to the basket. To expand on that what I mean is every product has a default price, which is defined by the *product_cost* column in the **Product** table. The *product_session_price* within the **Basket** table contains a different price, to indicate price reductions for whatever reason. Although my output above shows the *product_session_price* column to actually be more than the original cost, just imagine these would be lower.

Assuming the above makes sense, I'd like to ***distinctly*** select the ***most*** common *product_session_price* for each product of each product interaction type.

Below is how I'd like the data to be returned:

```
product_name | product_cost | product_session_price | product_interaction | yearid | month_name | monthid

Panadol (x16)   $4.28             $4.00                Add to Basket    2017    January    1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28             $4.28                View             2017    January    1
Panadol (x16)   $4.28             $2.55                Buy              2017    January    1
Garden Hose     $19.99            $19.99                   Add to Basket    2017    January    1
Garden Hose     $19.99            $18.95                   View         2017    January    1
Garden Hose     $19.99            $16.75                   Buy  2017    January    1

// and so on...repeating the same for the dates specified with no duplicated records unless dates are different or the product_interaction type is different.
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In schema, "Date(day, Month, year)" table and table "time" you cold replace with timestamp type column in table "Basket" to know exact time item was placed in basket and then you wont need to check if month days exists in month.
If I am understand what you need, then you have to use aggregation function like [MIN](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-min-function.php) on product_session_price with group by to get lowest price or [COUNT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) with group by and [having](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause to get most common price.

Comment: Thank you, the reason the date/time is split like that is to emphasise normalisation as part of the CW. It is also supposed to be a data warehouse rather than a production database :)

Comment: What I have seen that max is separate date and time columns. And I think storing data variable is not any of 3NF violations. Did not get "as part of the CW" But its your design and you know details of project. ;)